trigger a foreground app by a script runnning in background (in same tty, linux)
tui.c: a simple ncurses hello world tui app:
// gcc -o tui tui.c -lncurses
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();                // start curses mode
    printw("Hello, World!");  // print Hello, World
    refresh();                // print it on the real screen
    getch();                  // wait for user input
    endwin();                 // end curses mode
    return 0;
}

test.c: a c program need to running on background (avoid blocking other terminal operations & tasks)
// gcc -o test test.c -lpthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int countdown = 2;

void start_tui(){
    system("./start.sh");
}

void sigusr1_handle(int signum){
    system("uptime");
}

void sigtstp_handle(int signum){
    _exit(0);
}

void* func2(void* callback){
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1_handle);                           // trap SIGUSR1
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handle);                           // trap SIGTSTP
    printf("this is func2 running...");
    sleep(3);
    int status;

    start_tui();                                               // just start the TUI app

    void (*reset_timer)() = callback;                          // set callback
    reset_timer();                                             // execute callback
    return NULL;
}

void reset(){                                                  // callback func definition
    countdown = 2;                                             // reset count down
}

void func1(){
    while(1){
        while(countdown > 0){                                  // timer 3s
            printf("count down: %d\n", countdown);
            sleep(1);
            countdown--;
        }
        printf("count down: %d\n", countdown);
        if(!countdown){                                        // segregate the process logic
            pthread_t thread;
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func2, reset);       // exec func2
            pthread_join(thread, NULL);                        // wait for thread end
            printf("func2 has stopped.\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    func1();
    return 0;
}

start.sh: called by above c program, to startup tui window.
#!/bin/sh

set -m   # enable job control

./tui    # invoke the ncurses tui app 

expected behavior:
$ ./test &      # this should be running in bg, so that no block on other user task on this tty
count down 2
count down 1
count down 0
hello world!    # tui window output on foreground
<press any key to exit from ncurse tui window, interrupt the tui thread>
count down 2
count down 1
count down 0

actual behavior:
$ ./test &      # this should be running in bg, so that no block on other user task on this tty
count down 2
count down 1
count down 0
hello world!    # tui window output on foreground
<try press any key to exit from ncurse tui window, interrupt the tui thread>

<OOPs, the ssh terminal logged out. ssh session is down>
<login again, the tui hello world process is still running...
<the keystroke wont convey msg to inner thread of a background process>

the question:
0 if the test binary run on foreground:
$ test

then everything work's fine, but terminal block to neglect all userinput.
1 how can a background running task invoke a foreground tui app, let the terminal input active for the foreground app?
2 I'm trying to bring the foreground tui app background, but let it accept for stdin and output to stdout of current terminal.

... Then you have concurrence over STDIN between your background task and foreground shell...

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub, yes, you are correct, the spawned threads are concurrently content the STDIN/STDOUT, so that should be the reason why the ssh terminal failed. if I startup the program by: ./test > /dev/null 2>&1 &, then ssh term wont crash.

this problem is related to terminal control of foreground shell & background tasks.
as @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub, answered below, a helpful way is to put the triggeable job in backgroud, mask its stdin/stdout to /dev/null, then keep the output to certain fd of a foreground job. But for ncurses-like interactive apps (in/out), put it background will lead to concurrency of terminal usage, it's another problem to solve indeed (nearly to implement one' own terminal controler simu).

I'ts near impossible to plan having a background task unexpectedly to take precedence over current TTY. Depending on what you're currently doing (editing some file with an editor), this may cause trouble!

Putting a triggeable job in background
For putting a job in backroung AND keep tty useable for other foregroung jobs, you have to free STANDARDS descriptors (STD I/O and STDERR):
Here is a minimal shell sample (tested under busybox, dash and others):
Nota instead of your helloworld program, I run uptime which will output something too.
#!/bin/sh

bgTask() {
    trap 'uptime >&4' USR1
    trap 'break' TSTP
    while :; do
        read -r _
    done
    echo "SUB-Process $$ ended." >&4
}

exec 4>&1
bgTask </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &

printf 'Task bgTask %d started!\nYou could trigg them by\n  - kill -USR1 %d
Then you could stop them by\n  - kill -TSTP %d\n' $! $! $!


Thanks for you quick answer, I'm checking & learning the essence from the above script.  I've update a more detailed example illustrating my pain according to the above script. Do you think I need to trigger the background running start.sh by a designated signal USR1:
void sigusr1_handle(int signum){ system("./start.sh");}
